# Container 'x' was not found

Tags: tosca

Does anybody work with Tosca (module) and has the same error in testcase:  **Container 'x' was not found**?

The attr is already adapted: XPath-> correct; Visible=true; ClassName -> correct.

What should be done, that the tosca can find this container?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it could be a maintenance error, i.e. certain container does not exist anymore or
you should re-scan new one. I'm using e.g. selector data-tosca instead of xpath